# "Make searchable" and "Hide from searches" works on Status tab, but not File CV tab

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs, cv

I'm using IE8 on Windows 7 64 bit.

I logged in to http://careers.stackoverflow.com to hide my CV from searches. When I went to the *file cv* tab and tried clicking *Hide From Searches*, nothing happened.  However, when I click *Hide From Searches* on the *status* tab, it works correctly.  Once I toggled it from *status*, I noticed the same problem when the link changed to *Make Searchable*.

I'm not sure if this is a problem on the website or my local machine.

Comment: I had the same problem. I tried IE and Chrome